# Ruby code in my html.erb file not executed during Cucumber test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm creating a Ruby on Rails web app and have an index.html.erb file for one of my views that contains the following code:

```
<div class="container" id="quickTickets">
    <% Game.all.each do |game| %>
        <h2>
            <%= link_to game.name, game_tickets_path(game.id), :id => "gameid_"+game.id.to_s %>
        </h2>
    <%end%>
</div>
```

The code works correctly when I view it in a browser and displays a header for each game that links to a separate page. However, when I run a Cucumber/Capybara test to simulate clicking on one of the headers, it fails.

The test fails because the block of Ruby code above is not executed when the Cucumber test is run, so the page ends up containing an empty `<div>`.

For example, when I make a call to `print page.html` to examine the HTML my Cucumber test is operating on, it displays the following:

```
<div class="container" id="quickTickets">
</div>
```

I've spent hours trying to find any documentation or previous bugs like this but haven't found a solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the container div is in the output the code is being evaluated.  Whats likely happening is that you actually don't have Game objects to show.  This is either because you haven't created any Game objects in the test, or because you are using a JS capable driver and haven't configured your tests to not use transactions (https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup)

Comment: I got it to work by adding Game objects to my db directly in my Cucumber test. If I understand correctly, you must explicitly create Game objects in the Cucumber test itself, rather than having the test interact with the db?

Comment: @user1874182  Tests are generally run in their own environment with their own database instance, and that database instance is cleared between each test (or if using a non-JS capable driver run in transaction mode so nothing every actually gets committed) so that tests are isolated from each other.  Therefore each test needs to create the objects in the database that it needs to test whatever it is testing.